# IdCookieManager with IdHTTP not sending cookies

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm logging onto a website, trying to get the cookies running. From what I understand, assigning a IdCookieManager to an IdHTTP and setting `AllowCookies:=true` should be all that I need to do, right? I succesfully receive a cookie after logging in, but when I try to navigate further, the cookie is not being sent.

Here is the code I have:

```
procedure TForm1.Login;
var data: TStringList;
begin
  data:=TStringList.Create;

  try
    IdHTTP.Get('http://navratdoreality.cz/'); // Here I receive Set-Cookie

    data.Add('ACTION=check_adult');
    data.Add('check=18plus');

    Memo1.text:=IdHTTP.Post('http://navratdoreality.cz/',data); // Here the 
     // request contains the cookie and I get a succesfully-logged page in 
     // response, no more set-cookie
  except
    ShowMessage('err');
  end;

  data.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Navigate;
var ms:TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Get('http://www.navratdoreality.cz/?p=view&id='+Edit1.Text, ms); 
    // the request doesn't contain any cookies, even though the cookie from 
    // logging is saved in IdCookieManager

    ms.Position:=0;
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ms, TEncoding.UTF8);
  except
    ShowMessage('err');
  end;

  ms.Free;
end;
```

I don't know what might be the problem. My Indy is 10.5.8.0. If you are going to look at the site, beware, some of it is nsfw.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was a very stupid question. The problem was that the *login* part had `http://navratdoreality.cz`, whereas the next part had `http://www.navratdoreality.cz`. Both URLs displayed the same, but they were apparently different for the IdCookieManager, so that's why the cookie wasn't sent.

Comment: From a cookie's perspective, `navratdoreality.cz` and `www.navratdoreality.cz` are separate domains, and thus cannot share cookies with each other unless the cookie's attributes allow that sharing.